# How to prevent UITextView text moving to top on typing?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitextview

I want to prevent `UITextView` moving my text to top when I start a new line. In my app I expand/increase my `UITextView` height constraint size, so it has an enough space to continue showing text without moving the text to top and scroller appearing.

How can I prevent it? Can I turn off this feature? So when I'll add a new line to my `textView` it will not move my text to top and show me scroller? Because I have a space there.

Comment: Please try this https://github.com/MatejBalantic/MBAutoGrowingTextView

Comment: @matloobHasnain I want to fix my issue. Why do you offer me GitHub repo???

Comment: If a mature tool already available, why you are trying to reinvent same tool again.but its all up to you you can get some help to this repo as well.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the scrolling in `UITextView` i.e. un-check scrolling.

[image]